# Compiling First Obj-C source under Windows

Tags: objective-c, mingw, gnustep

I'm trying to compile for the first time, a Obj-C source under Windows 7.
I installed GNUstep and when I try to compile a simple hello world file it says to me
I had MinGW installed before with CodeBlocks fwiw...

Here is the error message I get from the GNUstep shell:

[image: screenshot]

EDIT: I tryed to add this GNUmakefile

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

APP_NAME = PanelTest
PanelTest_OBJC_FILES = main.m

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/application.make
```

but nothing changes.

EDIT 2: See @crashmstr reply to overcame the issue.

Now when I compile it says to me this

> fatal error: Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory
>   compilaion terminated.

What should I do?

Comment: There isn't even close to enough information here to solve your problem.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the error message picture

Comment: wow, instead of copying one 2 lines from the console you create a screenshot.

Comment: It didn't let me right-click them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C:\` is leaving you in the cd command, and in the next line, you are then adding `g++` to send to the `cd` command.

Note the `>` in front of `g++` instead of the `$`, plus the fact that it says `sh: cd: C:g++`

In the shell, you need to use Unix style paths and `/` as the path separator.

Comment: fatal error: Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory compilaion terminated.

Comment: I'd say that is a new question.

Comment: I don't know, title would be the same. What should I do?

Comment: Title might be the same, but the answers would no longer be valid. I would guess though that you are missing environment variables (inside the shell) to point to where the headers and libraries are. And no, I don't know anything about that shell or its usage.

Answer (score 0):

Is your path set correctly?  The error message I see in your screenshot refers to `g++` was not found.

Comment: where can i set my g++ path?

Comment: should I add g++ to my system variables under advanced system preferences?

Comment: I changed the PATH in enviroment variables, but nothing... Same error messages

Comment: sometimes you have to restart the terminal for the changes to PATH to show up.